# How to optimize deleting rows on google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I've been working on some code to automatically format, filter and delete rows based on some cell values.

While my script is working, I'm concerned about how fast it executes. I've been trying it on a 279 rows tab, with only two rows to delete, and it took me 3 minutes, which seems huge, especially as I aim to use it on tabs with 1000+ rows, and potentially between 200/300 rows to delete. Would you see ways to improve the execution time ?

Here's my code :

```
function Delete() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Copy");
  const range = sheet.getRange("A5:O");

  //Get Filter
  let filterrem = range.getFilter();
  Logger.log(filterrem);
  //Remove Filter if existing
  if(filterrem){
    filterrem.remove();
  };

  //Create a new Filter
  range.createFilter();
  //Get Filter and add criteria to Col 13
  let filter = range.getFilter();
  let criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
                                .whenTextEqualTo("Yes")
                                .build();
  filter.setColumnFilterCriteria(13, criteria);

  //Delete Unfiltered Rows
  var j = sheet.getLastRow();
  for (var i = j; i > 5; i--) {
    if (!sheet.isRowHiddenByFilter(i)) {
      sheet.deleteRow(i);
    }
  };

  //Remove Filter Criteria on Col 13
  filter.removeColumnFilterCriteria(13);
  //Sort Col 8 by ascending order
  filter.sort(8, true);
};
```

Thank you !

Comment: Use sheets api(Advanced Google services) with batch request. Tanaike here has multiple answers with code samples.

Comment: Thanks TheMaster, I'll have a look !

Comment: I'll bet `deleteRow()` is the real performance killer here. You could test this by logging the date/time at each major section of your function to make sure that's the bottleneck. Now if the rows are consecutive you can use `deleteRows` (https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleterowsrowposition,-howmany] to delete more than one row at a time (slightly faster).

Comment: You best best on deleting is not to.  Save all of the rows you want and then clear the entire range and use setValues to write out the data all at once.